# My output on Emacs is showing the whole code not the output

Tags: emacs

I put my code in and compile it but then it shows up in word pad with no output just the whole code. is something wrong with Emacs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like compile mode is misconfigured, or you're putting in the wrong compile command when it prompts you. You're on windows, where attempting to execute a file that isn't itself executable will instead launch the program registered to view or edit that type of file. You must have wordpad configured as the default viewer for the files you're editing.